# How do I stop windows 10 install games automatically?

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday my windows 10 installed these unexpected games automatically:

[image: installed unexpected games] [image: installed unexpected games]

> 12 Labours of Hercules III Girl P..., All Casual Games, All Enthusiast
>   Games, All Family Games, All Kids Games, Azkend 2 The World Beneath,
>   Building the Great Wall of China..., Command and Conquer Tiberiu...,
>   Coyote The Outlander, Delicious Emily's Wonder Wedd..., Entwined The
>   Perfect Murder, Family Vacation 2 Road Trip, Home Makeover, IGT Slots
>   Paradise Garden, Imperial Island Birth of an Empire, Insane Cold Back
>   to the Ide Age, Jewel Match Snowscapes, Living Legends Frozen Beauty
>   C..., Lost Lands Dark Overlord Collec..., Malor Memoirs Collector's
>   Edit..., Mystery Expedition Prisoners of..., Plagiarii, Polar Bowler
>   1st Frame

.

As far as I remember I only had Solitaire.

I use Windows Defender. I'm on the latest Windows 10.

After searching online, I followed one of advices just now: I turned off Updates from more than one place in my Settings. I don't know if this could solve my problem.

Help?

UPDATE

Guys, that link solved my problem. After observing for about a month, my Win 10 didn't install any unexpected new games or anything secretively. Thank you.

Comment: You installed something which installed those, those are Win32 apps

Comment: I'd hit your system with a malware scan

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for letting me know that. I'll search online about Win32 apps.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for your suggestion. I just did Windows Defender full scan last night though, but probably I scanned it while my system installing those unexpected apps. I saw from Settings that Windows Defender supports malware scan, no?

Comment: @Moab I followed that advice to set No (your device might not work as expected) on my System Properties Hardware. I don't know if this work but I'll see if this system would still install anything secretively for about a month, by checking my All Apps after Start Menu. I'll update my question if that link solved my problem. Thank you all guys for your help.